# Read from bytes not filename to convert audio

Tags: python, pydub

I have small-sized sound files stored in `MongoDB` as `BSON`. 
Task is to retrieve Binary data from the database, convert it to an appropriate format and send back to the front end. 
The problem is with the converting. I have found `pydub` can be used for this.

My code is as follows

```
 query_param = json_data['retriever']
 query_param1 = query_param.replace('"', "");
 data = db.soundData
 y = data.find_one({'name': query_param1})
 s = y['data'] // here I retrieve the binary data 
 AudioSegment.from_file(s).export(x, format="mp3")
 return send_file(x, 'audio/mp3')
```

The question is with Audiosegment line as it does not follow the standard of 
`AudioSegment.from_wav("/input/file.wav").export("/output/file.mp3", format="mp3")`
and an error of `'bytes' object has no attribute 'read'` is still thrown. Is it achievable with `pydub`?

Comment: What format is the binary data in? Wave?

Comment: @Jiaaro Yes it is

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`AudioSegment.from_file()` takes a file path or file-like object as it's first argument. Assuming you have the raw bytes of a whole wave file (including wave headers, not just the audio data) then you can:

```
import io
s = io.BytesIO(y['data'])
AudioSegment.from_file(s).export(x, format='mp3')
```

If you only have the bytes of the audio samples you would need to know some metadata about your audio data:

```
AudioSegment(y['data'], sample_width=???, frame_rate=???, channels=???)
```

- `sample_width` is the number of bytes in each sample (so for 16-bit/CD audio, you'd use `2`)
- `frame_rate` is number of samples/second (aka, sample rate, for CD audio it's `44100`)
- `channels` how many audio streams are there, stereo is `2`, mono is `1`, etc

Comment: You sir are legit the greatest, I've used pydub for so many different things and every time, it's working great. Thank you!

Comment: @Jiaaro sir could u pls help , i m fasing same issue - edit and pass wav file without saving https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63467345/how-to-pass-edited-wav-between-functions-without-saving-wav-in-between?noredirect=1#comment112232633_63467345

Comment: Worth noting that you may need to seek to 0 before AudioSegment.from_file(). This related issue helped https://stackoverflow.com/a/65340798/1786351