# boto3 S3 Object Parsing

Tags: python, amazon-s3, byte, boto3, wave

I'm trying to write a Python script for processing audio data stored on S3.

I have an S3 object which I'm calling using

```
def grabAudio(filename, directory):

     obj = s3client.get_object(Bucket=bucketname, Key=directory+'/'+filename)

return obj['Body'].read()
```

Accessing the data using

```
print(obj['Body'].read())
```

yields the correct audio information. So its accessing the data from the bucket just fine.

When I try to then use this data in my audio processing library (pydub), it fails:

`audio = AudioSegment.from_wav(grabAudio(filename, bucketname))`

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "split_audio.py", line 38, in <module>
    audio = AudioSegment.from_wav(grabAudio(filename, bucketname))
  File "C:\Users\jmk_m\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pydub\audio_segment.py", line 544, in from_wav
    return cls.from_file(file, 'wav', parameters)
  File "C:\Users\jmk_m\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pydub\audio_segment.py", line 456, in from_file
    file.seek(0)
AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'seek'`

What is the format of the object coming in from s3? Byte array I presume? If so, is there a way of parsing it into a .wav format without having to save to disk? I'm trying to refrain from saving to disk.

Also open to alternative audio processing libraries.

Comment: You can use `io.BytesIO` to create a file-like object from `bytes` and pass it to your library: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44437265/200603

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to Linas for linking a similar issue, and Jiaaro for the answer.

```
 import io
    s = io.BytesIO(y['data'])
    AudioSegment.from_file(s).export(x, format='mp3')
```

Allows me to pull directly from the bucket into memory with

```
obj = s3client.get_object(Bucket=bucketname, Key=customername+'/'+filename)

data = io.BytesIO(obj['Body'].read())
audio = AudioSegment.from_file(data)
```