# AudioSegment and BytesIO module gives "FileNotFoundError"

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-s3, boto3, wav, bytesio

I am trying to fetch .wav file from Amazon S3 and modify it using AudioSegment library. For fetching .wav file from S3, I have used boto3 and IO module. For Audio operations, I am using AudioSegment module.

When I fetch file from S3 using BytesIO and pass it to AudioSegment, I am getting "System can not find the file specified" error. Below is my code

```
import boto3
from pydub import AudioSegment
import io
client = boto3.client('s3')
obj = client.get_object(Bucket='<BucketName>', Key='<FileName>')
data = io.BytesIO(obj['Body'].read())
sound1 = AudioSegment.from_file(data)
```

I am getting error at AudioSegment.from_file(data)

> System can not find the file specified

Comment: Not familiar with any of this, but check your API docs. It looks like you are trying to pass a stream of bytes to something expecting an actual _file_ or even _filename_. These two things are not the same.

Comment: You're calling a method called  `from_file` so I assume it expects `data` to contain a filename. It probably doesn't?

Comment: I referred this link - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48997852/boto3-s3-object-parsing where jmkmay suggested above solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying the **format** argument for AudioSegment. For example:

```
sound1 = AudioSegment.from_file(data, format='mp3')
```